# Nutiteq GPS tracking

Tags: android, nutiteq

iam a newbie for this kind of development. im trying to create an android application which involves GPS tracking. i am using Nutiteq because i have to use openstreetmap as the default map. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by GPS tracking? If it is showing GPS location on map, then Nutiteq sample project (https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/) has several samples:
a) Simpler **HelloMap3D** demo has line-based animated GPS display, this is easier to use
b) **AnimatedLocationActivity** in AdvancedMap3D shows OpenGL-based animation for more advanced requirements

If you want to save locations and show tracks as lines or points, then you need a bit extra work. I would save data to Spatialite database. Same hellomap3d project has Spatialite layer for viewing, but there is also **SpatialLiteDbHelper.java** which has method **insertSpatiaLiteGeom()** which enables to save data persistently to the database, this is something you need to implement in your app. For viewing lines and points there is existing sample code: see **VectorFileMapActivity.java**.

GPS tracks tend to become long and slow to render. For this there is special method to simplify data: use something like in VectorFileMapActivity:

```
dataSource.setAutoSimplify(2, metrics.widthPixels);
```

This tells that line data (it does not apply to points) will be simplified based on map zoom, while after zoom in you will see full data (for smaller map area). This will enable to show GPS trakcs if you have many of them visible with thousands of points.

Answer (score 0):

The [Open GPS Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/) project uses open street map. Have a glance on their sources.